# setup.py giving syntax error while installing module

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, setup.py, pypi

I've been trying to learn Python via "Learn Python the Hard Way", and in ex46 he told us to put a script in bin and install it with setup.py.

My script name was script1.py
Here is my setup.py file:

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup

config = [
          'description': 'My Project',
          'author': 'My Name',
          'url': 'URL to get it at.',
          'download_url': 'Where to download it.',
          'author_email': 'My email.',
          'version': '0.1',
          'install_requires': ['nose'],
          'packages': ['NAME'],
          'scripts': ['bin/script1.py'],
          'name': 'projectname'
        ]
setup(**config)
```

Output:

```
File "setup.py", line 7
'description': 'My Project',
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

- I am using ubuntu 16.04 and python 2.7.13

Comment: FWIW, the SO Python Chat room regulars [do not recommend LPTHW](http://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints). If it's working for you, that's great, but please be aware that there are several problems with this book. Also be aware that Python 2 will reach its End Of Life in 2020, so you really ought to be learning Python 3, unless you need Python 2 to work on legacy code.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thank you, sir. I am about to finish this book and then I will move to leaning python 3. Is python 3 completely different from python 2.7 ?

Comment: No, Python 3 isn't _completely_ different from python 2.7, but there are some important differences. In particular, Python 3 makes a clear distinction between text and bytes, which allows it to have better handling of Unicode.

Comment: Learning Python 2 is waste of time now, as you're using Ubuntu 16.04, and Python 3 can be run with the simple `python3` command - it is preinstalled as most of the Python scripts on the operating system *require* Python 3.

Comment: I wouldn't say learning Python 2 is a waste of time, but I would strongly recommend dedicating your effort to Python 3 instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description is shown as a list (begins and ends with `[` and `]`) but should be a dict (begin and end with `{` and `}`).

A list is just that, a comma separated list of items, the start and end of which are indicated by brackets (`[` and `]`).  A dict on the other hand is a comma separated list of key/value pairs which are indicated by braces(`{` and `}`).  The error is telling you that the colon (which would separate a dictionary's key from its value) is out of place since it thinks it is a list.  By changing the beginning and ending brackets to braces, it will properly identify it as a dictionary.